# control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

Tags: c++, if-statement, return-type

Even after using default else statement I am getting this error

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if((a>b)&&(a>c))
    {        
        if(a>d)
            return a;
    }
    else if((b>c)&&(b>d))
    {  
        return b; 
    }
    else if(c>d)
    { 
        return c; 
    }
    else 
        return d;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a particular line number pointed out with this error? Is it pointing to the last brace of your function definition?

Comment: why the heck is this worth -6?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first `if` is the problem

```
if((a>b)&&(a>c))
{
    if(a>d)
        return a;
    // what about else?
}
```

If your outer condition is `true`, but the inner condition is `false`, it will not have any `return` case.

By the way, your method is a very convoluted way to solve this, or at least difficult to read. I would do something like this.

```
#include <algorithm>
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return std::max(std::max(a, b), std::max(c, d));
}
```

You could also use

```
#include <algorithm>
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return std::max({a, b, c, d});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the “control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]”
error happens during the compiling phase, when there is a possibility(branch) that your non-void function (which is defined to return a value) could not return a value. Although, depends on the input, it does not necessarily reach that dead-end.

Comment: This answer is a bit muddy, especially for someone new to C++. Is there a more straightforward way you can phrase this?

Answer (score 0):

*put else condition in first if:*

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
     if((a>b)&&(a>c))
    {        
        if(a>d)
            return a;
         else
             return d;
    }
    else if((b>c)&&(b>d))
    {  
        return b; 
    }
    else if(c>d)
    { 
        return c; 
    }
    else 
        return d;
}
```